# Dropdown on left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the elements when i click on the horizontal ellipsis button. I would like to show the sub elements inline with the parent, to the left of the button.

An image how it should look like:

[image: on click of 3 points]

Here is my dropdown code but its only down, and i dont know how to display it always on left. The icons are fontawesome icons, if someone could post a jsfiddle it would be great.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropleft-items"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I am using CSS Bootstrap.

Comment: This kind of feels like you are asking someone to code this **for** you...

Comment: This kind of is asking help how to do it, some code would be great, i just need the right hint :D

Comment: use `pull-left` class

Answer (score 1):

if i correctly understood u want something like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var menuWrapper = $('.menu'),
      button = menuWrapper.find('button'),
      menu = menuWrapper.find('ul.toggle-left');
  $(button).on('click', function(){
    $(this).prev(menu).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu{
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

ul.toggle-left{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul.toggle-left>li{
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.btn-toggle{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu" class="clearfix">
  <ul class="toggle-left clearfix">
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  <button class="btn" type="button" class="btn-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="false"></i></button>
</div>
  <div class="menu" class="clearfix">
  <ul class="toggle-left clearfix">
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  <button class="btn" type="button" class="btn-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="false"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: like in the image above, the menu to show on the left, inline with the button

Comment: @Muli u dont need drop down, u want drop to left ?
i correctly understood ?

Comment: yes i want to drop left, and inline with the button

Comment: I think this is good, thank you, could you tell me how to work it separately, cuz im using this more than once, and when i click one all are diplaying

Comment: i have placed it under table tr td, is it possible to target it separetly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120634/discussion-between-muli-and-ivan-karaman).